# Parsing a string made from a LINQ statement to a method

Tags: c#, linq

I want to pass only `e.Trip` of my `string.Format` to the method referenced in `tripChoose`. As of now, it tried to pass a string not formatted for the method. If I could just pass the Trip part of the string, it would work. Any suggestions?

```
private void LoadExpenseListSums()
{
    expenseTotalSelect.Items.Clear();
    var sortedList=
        from e in roster
        group e by e.Trip into expenseCollect
        select new { Trip = expenseCollect.Key, SumAmount = expenseCollect.Sum(e => e.Amount) };
    foreach (var e in sortedList)
        tripChoose.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | ${1}", e.Trip, e.SumAmount));
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `expenseTotalSelect`? This sounds like it's not actually a problem with LINQ, but with whatever control you're using - chances are you just need to add an object which has both the text and the appropriate value, and set appropriate bindings.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was sending it to another combo box for testing, it should refer to tripChoose.

Comment: Well that still doesn't answer the question of what tripChoose is, *exactly* - bear in mind that you haven't told us whether this is WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, something else...

Comment: It's a combo box, so it's a WinForms element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, now we actually know what we're dealing with, I suspect you want something like this:

```
private void LoadExpenseListSums()
{
    expenseTotalSelect.Items.Clear();
    var dateSorted =
        from e in roster
        group e by e.Trip into tripGroup
        select new { Trip = tripGroup.Key,
                     Text = string.Format("{0} | ${1}",
                                          tripGroup.Key,
                                          tripGroup.Sum(e => e.Amount) };
    tripChoose.DataSource = dateSorted;
    tripChoose.DisplayMember = "Text";
    tripChoose.ValueMember = "Trip";
}
```

This makes a few assumptions:
ase, 
- `roster` is an in-memory collection: if it's not, you'll probably need an `AsEnumerable` call before the formatting, to make that happen locally
- Anonymous types work with data binding; I'm not sure whether that's the case, but I'd hope it is

You then use the `SelectedValue` member later on to find the trip ID.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your expenseTotalSelect is an ASP.NET Select control and what you're doing ends up adding an  element in the result HTML identified only by text such as:

```
<select id='expenseTotalSelect'>
    <option>Hawaii | $5000</option>
    <option>London | $4000</option>
    ...
</select>
```

In your expenseTotalSelect.Items.Add call you would probably be better off doing the following:

```
expenseTotalSelect.Items.Add(
       new ListItem(string.Format("{0} | ${1}", e.Trip, e.SumAmount),e.Trip));
```

Now you'll get the following when you render to HTML:

```
<select id='expenseTotalSelect'>
    <option value='Hawaii'>Hawaii | $5000</option>
    <option value='London'>London | $4000</option>
    ...
</select>
```

And it will be easier to just reference `tripChoose.SelectedItem.Value` which will only contain the e.Trip value (Hawaii or London) for this example

Answer (score 0):

Think you should use an object as suggested in the comment, however assuming `expenseTotalSelect` is a `List<string>` and `tripChoose` is bound to it you could do this:

```
(string)tripChoose.SelectedItem.Split('|')[0].Replace(" ", string.Empty)
```

Comment: It should be referring to tripChoose! Sorry about that, I was sending the items to another combo box for testing.